# Can't successfully complete In App purchase transactions on next launch

Tags: iphone, ios4, in-app-purchase

For my unfinished transactions due to interruptions(incoming call etc.), I am getting updates when I relaunch the application as I am adding an observer to the payment queue. But how do I know which is the transaction that's being sent down the wire. I have tried this

```
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {               
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:               
                //Show a loading View   
                NSLog(@"Purchase Ongoing");

            break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
}

}

    -(void) completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *) transaction
    {

    NSString *productIdentifier = transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier;
    NSLog (productIdentifier);  

    //this line doesn't log anything. I run it in debug mode and I see productIdentifier as InvalidCFString (0x0). I guess it's nill.

    }
```

Is this because I couldn't finish the transaction properly before my app got killed. After killing, I do get the message that your In-App purchase was successful from Apple. It's just that I couldn't finish the transaction before my app got killed. The transaction was ongoing at that time. Trying to force finish the transaction before the app getting killed crashes the application saying "Can't finish an ongoing transaction" as I had not yet received the SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased notification.

Now when I relaunch, I get some response but I am not able to read it and unlock the functionality which I must as the amount has already been debited to the user's itunes account. How to tackle this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To avoid keeping failed transactions in the queue forever, you should check for all potential transaction states. You're not handling SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed not SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored at the moment.

Comment: I am handling them. I have just not posted the code here. But my question is still unanswered. There can be situations when no matter how much you try you can't finish a transaction. Like abrupt killing of the application. I don't send the application to background. I am explicitly killing it. Hence there is a good chance of having transactions that are unfinished. So when on relaunch, you get notified about them by Apple, how do you extract the relevant product information like transaction.payment.productIdentifier from it so that you can unlock corresponding functionality.

Comment: Turns out, I was accessing the productIdentifier using the wrong name it should be transaction.payment.productIdentifier. All this while, I was using transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier;

Comment: Good! Answer your own question in case somebody searches the same :)